# Event Listener Cache Clear

Tags: laravel, event-listener

Can someone help me on how to clear my cache using laravel event listener, cause i'm planning to clear my cache after logout of after logging in. can some one enlighten me about this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should cover the listening and clear of cache:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

// You would need to define this event..
use App\Events\Logout;

class LogoutListener
{
    public function handle(Logout $event)
    {
      // forget a particular key in cache, eg user (this will vary on what key you used to store it)
      Cache::forget('user_' . auth()->id());

      // or... remove everything in cache, but i would lean towards just removing what you need, like above
      Cache::flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

laravel have tag based cache https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#cache-tags, but it require array based caching , file based cache not support..
you can just add user id tag to every user cache key.

`Cache::tags(['user_id_xx])->put('key', 'value', 100);`

then clear,

`Cache::tags(['user_id_xx'])->flush();`